# C: Problems with scanf and printf

Tags: c, printf, scanf

I'm having issues with accepting user input and the printing its ascii value in C. I'm tasked with writing a program that simply takes a single char as input and prints out its ascii value, and only stops when the user inputs 0 (the ascii value of 0 is 48). My problem is that if the the printf seems to function one loop behind scanf.

```
while(x == 1){
    scanf("%c\n",&thisChar);
    ascii = thisChar;
    if(ascii == 48){
        x = -1;
    }
    printf("Ascii: %d\n", ascii);
}
```

For example, when I run this from the command line, I get something like this:

```
f  
0  
Ascii: 102  
f  
Ascii: 48
```

and then the program ends. With those same inputs, I want the output to be:

```
f  
Ascii: 102  
0  
Ascii: 48
```

and then end there. What is the error in my logic?

Comment: change `"%c\n"` to `" %c"`

Comment: Always check return value of `scanf` family of functions!

Comment: note that `ascii == '0'` is absolutely equivalent to `ascii == 48` only that it is easier to understand what your code is supposed to mean.

Answer (score 3):

`\n` character is the root cause of your problem.
Change

```
 scanf("%c\n",&thisChar);
```

to

```
 scanf(" %c",&thisChar);
```

---

EDIT: OP asked why a space before `%c` in `scanf` matters in output?

When you inputs the data to a program and press <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, an extra character `\n` is passed to the input buffer along with the input data. For Ex: If you want to enter `f` in your program then on pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> key, input buffers contains `f\n`. On first iteration of loop, character `f` is read by `scanf` leaving behind the `\n` in the buffer. On next iteration of loop, this `\n` is read by the `scanf` causing unexpected output.
To solve this issue you need to consume this `\n` before next read. Placing a space before `%c` specifier in `scanf` can consume any number of new-line characters.

Comment: The only difference being the space? I just tried that and it produced the same result.

Comment: Remove `\n` from your `scanf`.

Comment: Ok that worked! Can you explain why the new line character changed the output?

Comment: Actually, I just tried without the space before the %c and am getting a new error. Do you know why the space matters?

Comment: Yes. Do you need explanation?

Comment: Would love an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Did you consider using just [getchar(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getchar.3.html) ? (Perhaps [fflush(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fflush.3.html) could be needed)... Also *stdin* in a terminal is a complex beast. See [tty demystified](http://www.linusakesson.net/programming/tty/index.php).

The *kernel* (not only the `libc`)  is sort of buffering each tty lines (see [line discipline](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_discipline)).

See also [ncurses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ncurses) and [GNU readline](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html).

Answer (score 0):

Dont use \n in scanf() .

Remove "\n" and execute